# Asciidoc hugo site with netlify

Tags: rubygems, hugo, netlify

I want to build a hugo site with asciidoc content and host it in netlify. I was able to run the site locally after installing ascii and asciidoctor in my windows machine.

```
gem install asciidoc
gem install asciidoc
```

Prior to this, I got below error in my console and no content in the browser.

```
ERROR 2018/11/11 03:05:08 asciidoctor / asciidoc not found in $PATH: Please install.
8:35:09 AM:                   Leaving AsciiDoc content unrendered.
8:35:09 AM: ERROR 2018/11/11 03:05:08 asciidoctor / asciidoc not found in $PATH: Please install.
8:35:09 AM:                   Leaving AsciiDoc content unrendered.
8:35:09 AM: ERROR 2018/11/11 03:05:08 asciidoctor / asciidoc not found in $PATH: Please install.
8:35:09 AM:                   Leaving AsciiDoc content unrendered.
```

**Now** m getting the same error in netlify site build and it's getting failed during deployment.

Can someone please suggest any missing additional setup or configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add your `/Gemfile` and `/Gemfile.lock` to your project root for `asciidoc`. Netlify uses them to identify that the build needs Ruby included.

`Gemfile` (example)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'asciidoc'
```

You can use `bundle install` locally to create `Gemfile.lock` from a `Gemfile`

```
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install
```

You can also set Ruby version via a `/.ruby-version` file. [See docs for supported Ruby versions on Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/#build-environment-variables).

Comment: Thanks. This is a experimental site for personal use. What factors should be considered for choosing the version for Hugo and ruby and how it's going to affect the current or future build.

Comment: Those are going to be the versions that your app supports. I cannot answer that question for you. But I would suggest you try to use the latest stable releases.